# Getting Questions WITHOUT a Bounty attached in Data Explorer

Tags: support, bounties, data-explorer

I've been trying to figure out how to get the number of Questions WITHOUT a Bounty attached to them in [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). I feel this should be a reasonably simple problem to solve, but I can't quite get there.

I've tried something simple like:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Posts
INNER JOIN Votes on Posts.Id = Votes.PostId
WHERE PostTypeId = 1 -- Is a question
AND Votes.BountyAmount is NULL -- Has No Bounty
AND Posts.CreationDate > DateAdd(day, -30, getdate()) -- Past 30 days
```

But the problem is that it returns a result for every ANSWER.

I know there must be a very logical way to approach this with SQL, but I'm struggling to find it. Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You better join the [Votes table on votetypeid = 8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100) because that links to the question where the bounty was started. The [following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/463104) lists questions that have had no bounties attached to them, ever. Do notice that for Stack Overflow this query times out, hence the top 1000:

```sql
select top 1000 
       q.id as [Post Link]
from posts q 
where q.posttypeid = 1 -- Q
and q.CreationDate > DateAdd(day, -30, getdate()) -- Past 30 days
and q.id not in (
   select p.id
   from posts p 
   inner join votes v on v.postid = p.id
   where v.votetypeid = 8 -- bounty started
)
```

Keep in mind that you'll never get more then 50,000 records returned.